# Looping through nested data and displaying object properties and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, javascript-objects

In my React app, I'm looking for a clean way to loop through the following dynamic data structure and display the object properties and values.

Sample data:

```
data: {
   company: [
      {
         company_name: "XYZ Firm",
         company_email: "hello@xyz.com",
         company_phone: 91982712,
      }
   ],
   shareholders: [
     {
         shareholder_name: "Lin",
         percentage: 45
     },
     {
         shareholder_name: "Alex",
         percentage: 10
     },
   ],
   employees: [
     {
         employee_name: "May",
         employee_email: "may@xyz.com"
     },
   ]
}
```

The output I want is:

```
company_name: XYZ Firm
company_email: hello@xyz.com
company_phone: 91982712

shareholder_name: Lin
shareholder_percentage: 45

shareholder_name: Alex
shareholder_percentage: 10

employee_name: May
employee_email: may@xyz.com
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
//data contains the entire object
const profileInfo = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
   let profileSection = [];
   for (let values of data[key]) { //retrieve the objects of each "section" e.g., company, shareholders
      Object.keys(values).map(key => {
         profileSection.push(<p>{key}: {values[key]}</p>);
      })
   }
   return profileSection;
})
```

I'm able to achieve the intended results but I'm not sure if it's the best solution in terms of performance. Having nested `Object.keys().map`seems a bit off to me.

Note: User will be able to add more shareholders/employees.

Comment: A suggestion: write the best code you can, trying not to be TOO stupid about performance, and then only optimize for performance if you've got a measurable problem.  My guess is that for the size data you're ever going to want to deal with in a UI, the double `.keys().map()` will not have any noticeable effect.  And besides, you're still only looping over the relevant data once.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll take note of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a somewhat shorter version using [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```js
var data = { company: [ { company_name: "XYZ Firm", company_email: "hello@xyz.com", company_phone: 91982712, } ], shareholders: [ { shareholder_name: "Lin", percentage: 45 }, { shareholder_name: "Alex", percentage: 10 }, ], employees: [ { employee_name: "May", employee_email: "may@xyz.com" }, ] };

let profileInfo = [];

Object.values(data).flat().forEach((item) => {
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    profileInfo.push(key + ": " + value);
  });
});

console.log(profileInfo);
```

Comment: I like the approach. Didn't really use `Object.values()` and `flat()` before. Thanks for sharing!